# How to avoid circular reference in python - a class member creating an object of another class and passing self as parameter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, design-patterns

I need some help in terms of 'pythonic' way of handling a specific scenario.

I'm writing an Ssh class (wraps paramiko) that provides the capability to connect to and executes commands on a device under test (DUT) over ssh.

```
class Ssh:
    def connect(some_params):
        # establishes connection
    def execute_command(command):
        # executes command and returns response
    def disconnect(some_params):
        # closes connection
```

Next, I'd like to create a Dut class that represents my device under test. It has other things, besides capability to execute commands on the device over ssh. It exposes a wrapper for command execution that internally invokes the Ssh's execute_command. The Ssh may change to something else in future - hence the wrapper.

```
def Dut:
    def __init__(some params):
        self.ssh = Ssh(blah blah)

    def execute_command(command)
        return self.ssh.execute_command(command)
```

Next, the device supports a custom command line interface for device under test. So, a class that accepts a DUT object as an input and exposes a method to execute the customised command.

```
def CustomCli:
    def __init__(dut_object):
        self.dut = dut_object
    def _customize(command):
        # return customised command
    def execute_custom_command(command):
        return self.dut.execute_command(_customize(command))
```

Each of the classes can be used independently (CustomCli would need a Dut object though).

Now, to simplify things for user, I'd like to expose a wrapper for CustomCli in the Dut class. This'll allow the creator of the Dut class to exeute a simple or custom command.
So, I modify the Dut class as below:

```
def Dut:
    def __init__(some params):
        self.ssh = Ssh(blah blah)
        self.custom_cli = Custom_cli(self) ;# how to avoid this circular reference in a pythonic way?

    def execute_command(command)
        return self.ssh.execute_command(command)

    def execute_custom_command(command)
        return self.custom_cli.execute_custom_command(command)
```

This will work, I suppose. But, in the process I've created a circular reference - Dut is pointing to CustomCli and CustomCli has a reference to it's creator Dut instance. This doesn't seem to be the correct design.
What's the best/pythonic way to deal with this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards

Sharad

Comment: Why do you think this circular reference is something you must avoid?

Comment: 1. From what I understand, it isn't a good design practice. 2. Some constraints may come into picture - for e.g., __del__ won't be executed.

Comment: There are cases where maintainable, straightforward code beats good design. Python's garbage collection is explicitly capable of handling circular references - you're in good company when using them. Really the only problem comes from having `__del__` in a reference cycle; in that case, `__del__` is usually the bigger problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

In general, circular references aren't a bad thing. Many programs will have them, and people just don't notice because there's another instance in-between like `A->B->C->A`. Python's garbage collector will properly take care of such constructs.

You can make circular references a bit easier on your conscience by using weak references. See the `weakref` module. This won't work in your case, however.

If you want to get rid of the circular reference, there are two way:

1. Have `CustomCLI` inherit from `Dut`, so you end up with just *one* instance. You might want to read up on Mixins.

   ```
   class CLIMerger(Dut):
       def execute_custom_command(command):
           return self.execute_command(_customize(command))
           # use self^ instead of self.dut

   class CLIMixin(object):
       # inherit from object, won't work on its own
       def execute_custom_command(command):
           return self.execute_command(_customize(command))
           # use self^ instead of self.dut

   class CLIDut(Dut, CLIMixin):
       # now the mixin "works", but still could enhance other Duts the same way
       pass
   ```

   The Mixin is advantageous if you need several cases of merging a CLI and Dut.
2. Have an explicit interface class that combines `CustomCli` and `Dut`.

   ```
   class DutCLI(object):
       def __init__(self, *bla, **blah):
           self.dut = Dut(*bla, **blah)
           self.cli = CustomCLI(self.dut)
   ```

   This requires you to write boilerplate or magic to forward every call from `DutCLI` to either `dut` or `cli`.